# Cannot Access remote VLAN from LAN

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-catalyst, cisco-nexus

[image: My Network Setup]

My WS-650E is connected to the Nexus 5000 as described in the image. The Nexus has a 10G P2P link to remote Site on 172.16.1.0/24 subnet. There is no router between the 2 sites and the IP on the remote switch is 172.16.1.2/24.

I can ping the hosts on 172.16.1.0 subnet from the WS-650E but none of the hosts from my internal network (Vlan 100) connect to any hosts on the 172.16.1.0 (Vlan 174) network.

What config am I missing?

Nexus:

```
vrf context management
vlan 1
vlan 174

port-profile default max-ports 512


interface Vlan1

interface Vlan174
  no shutdown
  ip address 172.16.1.1/24

interface Ethernet2/1
  switchport access vlan 174

interface Ethernet2/2
  switchport access vlan 174

ip route 0.0.0.0/0 172.16.1.200

no system default switchport shutdown
```

WS-650-E

```
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
redundancy
 main-cpu
  auto-sync running-config
 mode sso
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
vlan access-log ratelimit 2000
!         
vlan 2
 name MANAGEMENT
!
vlan 10
 name WORKSTATION
!
vlan 11
 name GUEST
!
vlan 12
 name WIRELESS_WORKSTATION
!
vlan 30
 name VOICE
!
vlan 50
 name SERVERFARM
!
vlan 60
 name WIRELESS_BACKBONE
!
vlan 101
 name ASA_HA
!         
vlan 174  
 name REMOTE
!         
track 10 ip sla 10 reachability

interface Port-channel1
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 storm-control broadcast level 5.00
 storm-control action shutdown
!
interface Port-channel2
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-channel3
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-channel4
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 storm-control broadcast level 5.00
 storm-control action shutdown

interface TenGigabitEthernet3/7
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 174
 switchport mode access
 udld port aggressive

interface Vlan1
 shutdown
!         
interface Vlan2
 ip address 
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 
!
interface Vlan11
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan12
 ip address 
!
interface Vlan30
 ip address
!
interface Vlan60
 ip address 
!
interface Vlan101
 ip address 
!
interface Vlan174
 ip address 172.16.1.200 255.255.255.0

router eigrp 10
 network 192.168.....
 network 192.168.....
 network 192.168.....
 network 192.168.....
 network 192.168.....

ip default-gateway 192.168.255.1
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!         
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.255.1 track 10
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.255.9 20
ip route 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 Vlan174
```

Comment: Is Vlan 100 on the Catalyst or on the Nexus? What is the default gateway for the hosts on Vlan 100? Where is that gateway IP address configured (on the Nexus or on the Catalyst)? How about just pasting the configs from the Catalyst and the Nexus after removing sensitive information?

Comment: We need to see the network device configurations.

Comment: @mere3ortal vlan 100 is on WS-650E. The default gateway for the hosts on VLAN 100 is the WS-650E. The default gateway is configured on WS-650E. I added the relevant info on the image but will update the questions with the configs later.

Comment: @LuckyChingi could you post the full configurations of both switches? Remember to remove all passwords and/or public IP adresses.

Comment: @mere3ortal - I updated the question with config

Comment: @RonMaupin the config question has been updated with the config

Comment: @Cown  the config question has been updated with the config

Comment: When you say VLAN 100, I assume you are referring to the 192.168.255.X network? Where is the L3 gateway for the subnet configured? Is the 650 learning that route via EIGRP?

Comment: Oops! sorry, its VLAN 10 not VLAN 100. 192.168.255.X is a /30 connected to the firewall.

Comment: @LuckyChingi what happens when try to traceroute from your workstation VLAN 10 subnet to the 172.16.1.0 subnet?

Comment: @Cown there is no reply when I ping. When I try tracert, it goes to the gateway for vlan 10 (255.254) and times out. I can ping hosts on Vlan 174 from the WS-650E switch

Comment: @LuckyChingi is VLAN 10 how the 650 connects to the firewall? From your config above I do not see IP configured for VLAN 10. Can you ping between the devices connected with the 192.168.255.X/30 subnet? It would be if you include the internal subnets and how your firewall is connected into this.

Comment: @A-A-Ron VLAN 10 has 192.168.235.254 - this is also the gateway ip for hosts on VLAN 10. 650 is directly connected to the firewall. Since I dont have a 10G port on the firewall, I am using a 10G switch to connect to the remote LAN. This was working fine when the remote VLAN 174 link was connected directly on the 650, due to business requirements, I had to move it to a newer switch and now the hosts VLAN 10 cannot access hosts on VALN 174

Comment: Can you change one of the remote hosts default gateway to .200 and then see if you can ping it from an internal host?

Comment: @A-A-Ron you are a champ! I realised the GW on the remote LAN was 1.1. Removed the IP on nexus and changed the IP on 650E ti 1.1 and its all started working. Thanks. Can you change your comment to answer?

Comment: @A-A-Ron please post an answer for OP to accept. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the gateway from the Nexus to the 650 for VLAN 174. :)